# Why decrement %rsp even when the reserved space on stack is never used?

Tags: c, assembly, stack, x86-64

I understand the convention of decrementing `%rsp` to reserve space for local variables at the beginning of a function in x86-64 assembly. However, in the below function, `%rsp` is decremented but the reserved space of 8 bytes on the stack is never used in the function. So why would the compiler decrement `%rsp` at the beginning? Source code and compiler information are not available.

```
0000000000400ef0 <phase_1>:
    0x0000000000400ee0 <+0>:    sub    $0x8, %rsp 
    0x0000000000400ee4 <+4>:    mov    $0x402400, %esi 
    0x0000000000400ee9 <+9>:    callq  0x401338 <strings_not_equal>
    0x0000000000400eee <+14>:   test   %eax, %eax
    0x0000000000400ef0 <+16>:   je     0x400ef7 <phase_1+23>
    0x0000000000400ef2 <+18>:   callq  0x40143a <explode_bomb>
    0x0000000000400ef7 <+23>:   add    $0x8, %rsp
    0x0000000000400efb <+27>:   retq
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
If the reason is to give the stack 16-byte alignment, here is another example that seems to be a contradiction. Doesn't `subq $16, %rsp` at the beginning of `call_incr` break the 16-bit alignment of stack prior to `call incr`? Why not just decrement `%rsp` by 8 bytes?

Source:

```
long incr(long *p, long val) {
    long x = *p;
    long y = x + val;
    *p = y;
    return x;
}

long call_incr() {
    long v1 = 1000;
    long v2 = incr(&v1, 3000);
    return v1+v2;
}
```

Assembly (compiled with `gcc -Og -fno-stack-protector -S`)

```
incr:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    addq    %rax, %rsi
    movq    %rsi, (%rdi)
    ret
    .cfi_endproc

call_incr:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $16, %rsp   # why decrement by 16 bytes here?
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    movq    $1000, 8(%rsp)
    movl    $3000, %esi
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
    call    incr
    addq    8(%rsp), %rax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: To give the stack 16 byte alignment. Calling the function pushes an 8 byte return address on the stack so the function needs to allocate 8 more bytes to align the stack again.

Comment: @RossRidge: Make that an answer. Also mention that the reason alignment is mandatory here is to meet the ABI calling other functions (`strings_not_equal`, `explode_bomb`).

Comment: @RossRidge: Thanks for pointing out the 16-byte alignment. But in the additional example in my edit, why does the compiler decrement `%rsp` by 16 instead of 8 bytes in `call_incr`?

Comment: The `subq $16, %rsp` is optimised out on my machine at `-O2`

Comment: It's probably allocating 16 bytes on the stack because you have 16 bytes of local variables (`v1` and `v2`) and it's not bothering to align the stack because it determined that `incr` doesn't actually need the stack to be aligned. If you remove the definition of `incr` then the compiler allocates 24 bytes on the stack which results in a correctly aligned stack in case `incr` needs it.

Comment: @RossRidge: Thank you for being helpful.